# How to write decoded text string to PDF file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

This place is my last resort and sanctuary.

With my limted coding knowledge I have been ale to get around VBA quite well but I am now stuck where I need help from the pro's.

I'll explain:
There is an XML file which will be read by the SUB using XPATH (the XML follows a certain structure but is not fixed). At a certain point it finds data in the segment  and decodes it (BASE64) and holds this in memory (DecodedData) but when trying to write it to a textfile an error occures. Debugging shows that the error has to do with: FileResponse.Write DecodedData. When I write the encoded text string to file than it works as a charm but the decoded text string fails.

What am I overlooking?

```
Sub XMLProcessing()
'Public Sub Xml_To_Excel()'

Dim osh As Worksheet
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Dim xmlDoc As Object
Dim nodeXML_DECL_1 As Object
Dim nodesSEG_ATT  As Object
Dim nodeXML_DECL_BOID As Object
Dim nodeXML_DECL_DLVRNR As Object
Dim nodeXML_DECL_CONS As Object
Dim nodeXML_DECL_LRN As Object
Dim nodeXML_DECL_MRN As Object

Dim i As Integer, oRow As Integer, h As Integer
Dim x As Integer, j As Integer

' Clear Sheet'
'Call ClearCellsIDs
' Variables'
oRow = 15
' Sets'
Set osh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\response.xml")

Set nodeXML_DECL_1 = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagname("declarations")
Set nodesSEG_ATT = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/declarations")

Set nodeXML_DECL_BOID = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagname("businessObjectId")
Set nodeXML_DECL_CONS = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagname("consignmentNumber")
Set nodeXML_DECL_DLVRNR = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagname("deliveryNumber")
Set nodeXML_DECL_LRN = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagname("localReference")
Set nodeXML_DECL_MRN = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagname("customsRegistrationNumber")

' Processing Loop'
For i = 0 To nodeXML_DECL_1.Length - 1 'TEL HET AANTAL DECLARATIONS'
    oRow = oRow + 1
    osh.Range("D" & oRow) = nodeXML_DECL_BOID(i).text       ' BOID'
    osh.Range("E" & oRow) = nodeXML_DECL_CONS(i).text       ' CONSIGNMENT'
    osh.Range("F" & oRow) = nodeXML_DECL_DLVRNR(i).text     ' DLVRYNR
    osh.Range("G" & oRow) = nodeXML_DECL_LRN(i).text        ' LRN'
    osh.Range("H" & oRow) = nodeXML_DECL_MRN(i).text        ' MRN'

    'Loop through the childnodes of Declarations'
    For j = 0 To nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes.Length - 1 'TEL HET AANTAL CHILDNODES

        'ZOEK HET SEGMENT ATTACHMENTS
        If nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).tagname = "attachments" Then
            For h = 0 To nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes.Length - 1                  'moet met -1 om de loop goed af te ronden
            If nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(h).text = "UTB" Then
            osh.Range("I" & oRow) = nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(h).text
            ResponseFilename = nodeXML_DECL_CONS(i).text & "-" & nodeXML_DECL_DLVRNR(i).text & "-" & nodeXML_DECL_MRN(i).text & "-" & nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(h).text & ".txt"
            h = h + 1
                '==DECODE DATA CONTENT
                DecodedData = Base64Decode(nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(h).text)

                '==SAVE DECODED DATA CONTENT TO FILENAME IN FOLDER FROM SETTING
                Set fsoResponse = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set oFileResponse = fsoResponse.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UTB\" & ResponseFilename, True)

                oFileResponse.Write DecodedData
                oFileResponse.Close

            h = h - 1
            End If
            If nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(h).text = "WAYBILL" Then
            osh.Range("J" & oRow) = nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(h).text
            ResponseFilename = nodeXML_DECL_CONS(i).text & "-" & nodeXML_DECL_DLVRNR(i).text & "-" & nodeXML_DECL_MRN(i).text & "-WEGVOERING.pdf"
            h = h + 1 'DIT IS DE ENIGE MANIER OM DE DATA OP TE HALEN - POINTER MECHANISME
                '==DECODE DATA CONTENT

                DecodedData = Base64Decode(nodeXML_DECL_1(i).ChildNodes(j).ChildNodes(h).text)

                '==SAVE DECODED DATA CONTENT TO FILENAME IN FOLDER FROM SETTING
                Set fsoResponseWEGVOERING = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set oFileResponseWEGVOERING = fsoResponse.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UTB\" & ResponseFilename, True)

                oFileResponseWEGVOERING.Write DecodedData & vbCLRF
                oFileResponseWEGVOERING.Close
            h = h - 1
            End If
            Next
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

' Finish'
   MsgBox "Process Completed"
   End Sub

The XML is:

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
    <ns2:getChangedDeclarationsResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:de.aeb.xnsg.ic.bf">
        <result>
            <hasErrors>false</hasErrors>
            <hasOnlyRetryableErrors>false</hasOnlyRetryableErrors>
            <hasWarnings>false</hasWarnings>
            <declarations>
                <clientSystemId>EXCEL</clientSystemId>
                <customsProcessCode>IMPORT_NL</customsProcessCode>
                <businessObjectId>WOYTZCGCH60000057104</businessObjectId>
                <declarationTypeCode>IMPDECL</declarationTypeCode>
                <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
                <decisiveDate>
                    <dateInTimezone>2020-04-09 12:21:38</dateInTimezone>
                    <timezone>UTC+02:00</timezone>
                </decisiveDate>
                <localReference>WOYTZCGCH6AAB000035256</localReference>
                <customsRegistrationNumber>20NLK8SNQOAIDRWD54</customsRegistrationNumber>
                <commercialReferenceNumber>YT2009001227039485</commercialReferenceNumber>
                <deliveryNumber>YT2009001227039485</deliveryNumber>
                <organizationUnitClientSystem>YT2008401227008163</organizationUnitClientSystem>
                <consignmentNumber>501_07885824</consignmentNumber>
                <consignmentIdClientSystem>501_07885824</consignmentIdClientSystem>
                <status>
                    <statusCode>COMPLETE</statusCode>
                    <progressCode>COMPLETE</progressCode>
                </status>
                <isValid>true</isValid>
                <attachments>
                    <attachmentCode>UTB</attachmentCode>
                    <data>VGhpcyBzaG93cyB3aGVuIGl0IHdvcmtz</data>
                    <statusCode>NEW</statusCode>
                    <description>UTB (assessment of duties and taxes) Import Netherlands</description>
                </attachments>
                <attachments>
                    <attachmentCode>WAYBILL</attachmentCode>
                    <data>VGhpcyBzaG93cyB3aGVuIGl0IHdvcmtz</data>
                    <statusCode>NEW</statusCode>
                    <description>Waybill (Wegvoering) Import Netherlands</description>
                </attachments>
            </declarations>
            <declarations>
                <clientSystemId>EXCEL</clientSystemId>
                <customsProcessCode>IMPORT_NL</customsProcessCode>
                <businessObjectId>WOYTZCGCH60000027262</businessObjectId>
                <declarationTypeCode>IMPDECL</declarationTypeCode>
                <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
                <decisiveDate>
                    <dateInTimezone>2019-07-24 16:48:46</dateInTimezone>
                    <timezone>UTC+02:00</timezone>
                </decisiveDate>
                <localReference>WOYTZCGCH6AAB000015330</localReference>
                <customsRegistrationNumber>19NLJYHG7XA0CXWD50</customsRegistrationNumber>
                <commercialReferenceNumber>OOS19071902843-546</commercialReferenceNumber>
                <deliveryNumber>OOS19071902843-546</deliveryNumber>
                <organizationUnitClientSystem>OOS19071902843-301</organizationUnitClientSystem>
                <consignmentNumber>1180-60578022-3AA</consignmentNumber>
                <consignmentIdClientSystem>1180-60578022-3AA</consignmentIdClientSystem>
                <status>
                    <statusCode>COMPLETE</statusCode>
                    <progressCode>COMPLETE</progressCode>
                </status>
                <isValid>true</isValid>
                <attachments>
                    <attachmentCode>UTB</attachmentCode>
                    <statusCode>NEW</statusCode>
                    <description>UTB (assessment of duties and taxes) Import Netherlands</description>
                </attachments>
            </declarations>
            <declarations>
                <clientSystemId>EXCEL</clientSystemId>
                <customsProcessCode>IMPORT_NL</customsProcessCode>
                <businessObjectId>WOYTZCGCH60000055797</businessObjectId>
                <declarationTypeCode>IMPDECL</declarationTypeCode>
                <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
                <decisiveDate>
                    <dateInTimezone>2020-04-01 09:43:44</dateInTimezone>
                    <timezone>UTC+02:00</timezone>
                </decisiveDate>
                <localReference>WOYTZCGCH6AAB000034439</localReference>
                <customsRegistrationNumber>20NLK8H1D9AH1YWD51</customsRegistrationNumber>
                <commercialReferenceNumber>Y007701227013688</commercialReferenceNumber>
                <deliveryNumber>Y007701227013688</deliveryNumber>
                <organizationUnitClientSystem>Y005201227005658</organizationUnitClientSystem>
                <consignmentNumber>074_34620025</consignmentNumber>
                <consignmentIdClientSystem>074_34620025</consignmentIdClientSystem>
                <status>
                    <statusCode>COMPLETE</statusCode>
                    <progressCode>COMPLETE</progressCode>
                </status>
                <isValid>true</isValid>
                <attachments>
                    <attachmentCode>UTB</attachmentCode>
                    <data>VGhpcyBzaG93cyB3aGVuIGl0IHdvcmtz</data>
                    <statusCode>NEW</statusCode>
                    <description>UTB (assessment of duties and taxes) Import Netherlands</description>
                </attachments>
                <attachments>
                    <attachmentCode>WAYBILL</attachmentCode>
                    <data>VGhpcyBzaG93cyB3aGVuIGl0IHdvcmtz</data>
                    <statusCode>NEW</statusCode>
                    <description>Waybill (Wegvoering) Import Netherlands</description>
                </attachments>
            </declarations>
            <declarations>
                <clientSystemId>EXCEL</clientSystemId>
                <customsProcessCode>IMPORT_NL</customsProcessCode>
                <businessObjectId>WOYTZCGCH60000055665</businessObjectId>
                <declarationTypeCode>IMPDECL</declarationTypeCode>
                <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
                <decisiveDate>
                    <dateInTimezone>2020-04-01 09:43:43</dateInTimezone>
                    <timezone>UTC+02:00</timezone>
                </decisiveDate>
                <localReference>WOYTZCGCH6AAB000034307</localReference>
                <customsRegistrationNumber>20NLK8H1F2A06MWD50</customsRegistrationNumber>
                <commercialReferenceNumber>Y007101227006160</commercialReferenceNumber>
                <deliveryNumber>Y007101227006160</deliveryNumber>
                <organizationUnitClientSystem>Y005201227005658</organizationUnitClientSystem>
                <consignmentNumber>074_34620025</consignmentNumber>
                <consignmentIdClientSystem>074_34620025</consignmentIdClientSystem>
                <status>
                    <statusCode>COMPLETE</statusCode>
                    <progressCode>COMPLETE</progressCode>
                </status>
                <isValid>true</isValid>
                <attachments>
                    <attachmentCode>UTB</attachmentCode>
                    <data>VGhpcyBzaG93cyB3aGVuIGl0IHdvcmtz</data>
                    <statusCode>NEW</statusCode>
                    <description>UTB (assessment of duties and taxes) Import Netherlands</description>
                </attachments>
                <attachments>
                    <attachmentCode>WAYBILL</attachmentCode>
                    <data>VGhpcyBzaG93cyB3aGVuIGl0IHdvcmtz</data>
                    <statusCode>NEW</statusCode>
                    <description>Waybill (Wegvoering) Import Netherlands</description>
                </attachments>
            </declarations>
            <syncId>10</syncId>
            <isComplete>false</isComplete>
        </result>
    </ns2:getChangedDeclarationsResponse>
    </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

Comment: *"an error occures"* - please share the details of the error (error message and stack trace).

Comment: Apologies: Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Hhmmm, I've no experience with VBA, but I would assume that the result of `Base64Decode` is a byte array while `oFileResponse` is created as a text file. Writing a *byte array* without encoding information to a *text* file may not be implemented.